# Flutter just_audio - seektoNext with LoopMode.one enabled

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I would like to modify `just_audio` such that when `LoopMode` is set to `LoopMode.one` the `seekToNext` still goes to the next track in the playlist instead of repeating the same track. I would still want the track to repeat if it reaches the end without the user pressing the `skip_next` button. I believe this would be the expected behaviour from most users as this is how Spotify and most other music services function.

I tried a quick hack by modifying the code to momentarily disable `LoopMode.one` when the user presses the `skip_next` button but it seemed to just disable the button. I'm probably missing something obvious but any suggestions on the proper way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
        StreamBuilder<SequenceState?>(
          stream: player.sequenceStateStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) => IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous),
              iconSize: 50.0,
              onPressed:
                  // default code
                  // player.hasNext ? player.seekToNext : null,
                  //  modified code below not working
                  () {
                if (player.loopMode == LoopMode.off ||
                    player.loopMode == LoopMode.all) {
                  player.hasNext ? player.seekToNext : null;
                } else if (player.loopMode == LoopMode.one) {
                  player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.off);
                  player.hasNext ? player.seekToNext : null;
                  player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.one);
                }
              }),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can seek to the current index + 1:

```dart
final nextIndex = player.currentIndex + 1;
if (nextIndex < player.sequence.length) {
  player.seek(Duration.zero, nextIndex);
}
```

Note: if you are using shuffle mode, then use `player.effectiveIndices` to find the *actual* next index. For example, if it contains `[3, 2, 1, 0]` and `currentIndex` is 3, this list tells you that the `nextIndex` should be 2.

Comment: Thank you Ryan! It is working now. Great job on the just_audio Flutter package btw. Really appreciate the work you've done

Comment: This answer is working great except for controlling skip behaviour from the lock screen. Suggestions on what file I would need to edit to implement that @RyanHeise?

Comment: If you want complete control over the lock screen, it is recommended that you use audio_service directly rather than just_audio_background.

Comment: Thank Ryan. Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I meant was that I would like the next and previous buttons in the lockscreen to mirror the behaviour that I get from the player with your answer above (ignore loop one). I don't want to control loop behaviour from the lockscreen, just have it ignore the LoopMode.one setting. What file would I need to edit?

Comment: You were clear originally. You need to use audio_service directly for that level of control over the lock screen.

Comment: As an FYI to future users, I just commented out in just_audio_background the line //if (_repeatMode == AudioServiceRepeatMode.one) return index!;